# How to ignore empty textbox while searching?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, insert, command

> Hello! I want to ignore empty textboxes while i am searching for data in mysql.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{con.Open(); 


 MySql.Command mycommand (SELECT * FROM table WHERE " +
"Name Like '" + textbox1.Text + "'" +
"Nachname Like '" + textbox2.Text + "'" +
"Alter Like '" + textbox3.Text + "'",


con);
read = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(read);
datagridView.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();}
```

Comment: Assuming by 'ignore' you mean 'match anything', surely all you need to do is to trim any actual space characters present? Also, don't you need % round your strings if you are to get proper matching?

Comment: yes i tried it but it does not work with %

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches to this, but ideally, you should be using parameterized queries rather than string concatenation of search values; the second someone says they're searching for names like "O'reilly" your query is busted. (See google for "bobby drop tables").

However, since you are using string concatenation, why not just check the fields' values for empty while building the query?

Alternatively, use a parameterized query something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (@p1 = '' OR `Name` LIKE @p1) 
  AND (@p2 = '' OR `Nachname` LIKE @p2) 
  AND (@p3 = '' OR `Alter` LIKE @p3)
;
```

With this kind of usage:

```
mycommand.CommandText = theQueryAbove;
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textbox1.Text);
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textbox2.Text);
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", textbox3.Text);
var rdr = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The best solution is probably to construct a parameterized query, based on the relevant textboxes, that only contains parameters for the relevant ones. `Name LIKE @p1` can be faster than `(@p1 = '' OR Name LIKE @p1)`; the MySQL optimizer may automatically simplify it based on the `@p1` value, but it could still impair other ways it might have optimized such a query.

Comment: hello! i used your code, but it says to me that the connection must be open. But is wrote con.Open();

Comment: The command should be created using the open connection, either by passing the connection into it's constructor or using the connection's create command method.